# Why app slow down and use more than 40 mb Cache in android studio 2.0

Tags: android, performance

Recently i have updated android studio to 2.0, after that when i run app on device in debuging it use 40 mb or more cache and slow down but if i generate signed apk it use only 15 kb cache and work faster.
for reference image

[image]

Comment: have you updated your os to marshmellow too

Comment: @ankitagrawal yes, i have updated os to marshmellow.

Comment: i am seeing this too probably not a studio issue as i am seeing some strange numbers in detail page also

Comment: @ ankitagrawal  but this happen with two app on which i am working.

Comment: it is happening with all apps on marshmellow, i dont know what changed in marshmallow but after the update all apps have some strange cache size numbers

Comment: i just verified it is marshmallow issue not studio issue

Comment: may be but this number are different for signed apk.

Comment: for me signed apk also sees similar number

Comment: about the slowness you are right it is indeed slow startup on studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `MarshMallow` issue and not related to studio .

you can check with any app on `MarshMallow` and other OS you will see the difference, Probably marshmallow caching too much data about app , so possibly a bug is `MarshMallow` itself

```
About your Slow Startup Issue:
```

It is indeed slow startup on app with studio 2.0 , so this is probably a studio bug or it requires caching to use instant run i guess